# Matchmaking invite friend fails instantly when using GKMatchMakerViewController initWithRequest

Tags: ios, game-center, gkmatchmaker

this is my first question on Stack Overflow, so thanks in advance.  I am adding simple 1v1 mutliplayer functionality to my iPhone game, and I am struggling with the Matchmaker functionality.  Currently I have a ViewController acting as delegate for the default MatchMaker.  I get the matchmaker view controller to appear without issue, but as I attempt to invite the other Sandbox account I have as my friend, it fails instantly.  The accept dialog never pops up on the other device, and my invite handler never gets invoked.  Here is the code snippet I use to call the Match Maker:

```
- (IBAction)hostMatch: (id) sender
{
    GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
    request.minPlayers = 2;
    request.maxPlayers = 2;

    GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request];
    mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:mmvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Not really sure what I'm doing wrong, but it's probably something silly.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I encountered the exact same issue.  Did you find the solution?